# How to set name of pdf file when I download his?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have a problem with the file of pdf name in Google Chrome. I put my pdf in embed tag (code below).
And I when I download a file I see the default value "download.pdf" which I want to change. I have tried a lot of ways and some cases work in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Any ideas on how to change the default name of the file in embed tag in Chrome?

```
<embed width="100%" height="500px" src="data:application/pdf;base64,'
+ embedTemplateContentPlaceholder + '" type="application/pdf" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `download` Attribute to the name of your file. Something along the lines of this:

```
<embed width="100%" height="500px" src="data:application/pdf;base64,'
+ embedTemplateContentPlaceholder + '" type="application/pdf" download="filename.pdf"/>
```